# How to know if it's phishing or not in android apps?

Tags: android

In IM apps (not only), there is a browser frame that appears and prompts for example to connect to Facebook account, eBuddy for example.

[image: ![]()]

My question is: how can I know if this frame is from facebook.com and not a phishing website?
I know that the apps in the Play Store are legit (mostly at least), but how can we trust apps that we install from outside the store? Or is there any way to check the credentials form action?

Comment: If you trust the company that published the `eBuddy` application, it means you should trust that the frame is Facebook, there isn't a way to verify as a user its actually Facebook (that is the fault of Facebook not eBuddy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you're already logged-in on Facebook (with the app or default browser i'd say), it will only prompts you for confirmation that the third party app can use your Facebook account...

But in the case of your screenshot, I agree with you, it seems difficult to verify the site.

Comment: Thanks, actually I think this is the only way to know if this is phishing!